# A question on mean value inequality

Tags: inequality, big-list

It is known that mean value inequality is very useful. It is:

> For any $0 \le a_i (i=1,2,\dots,n)$, 
>   $$
> a_1 a_2\dots a_n\le (\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots + a_n}{n})^n \tag1
> $$

My question is: **how many ways by which the mean value inequality can be proved?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Paul - set $\lambda_i = 1/n$ in the proofs that SYZ's comment links to in order to make the connection

Comment: The inequality don't need to prove. The proof strategy is enough for me. Of course, more details proof are welcome.

Comment: @Paul I saw the tag Integral-inequality, and though I might have misunderstood you post. But I do believe that you are referring to the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean inequality, in which case you can still refer to this [AopsWiki](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Proofs_of_AM-GM) page, scroll down and the section below details 2 proofs of non-weighted AM-GM (the one you detailed above).

Comment: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) gives several proofs of AM-GM nequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method, which is often employed to prove AM-GM, is Cauchy induction.
Such proof is sketched in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75672/), [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27334/), [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/384979/), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_Cauchy_using_forward-backward-induction) and in many other places.

---

More about Cauchy induction:

- Cauchy induction at [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Cauchy_Induction)
- Proof of AM-GM using this type of induction at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_Cauchy). They call this technique forward-backward-induction.
- One section of Pete L. Clark's [notes on induction](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3200induction.pdf) is devoted to this type of induction. He calls it upward-downward induction.
- Perhaps also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97350/how-does-backwards-induction-work-to-prove-a-property-for-all-naturals)