# Proof about AM-GM inequality generalized

Tags: alternative-proof, means

Note: I'm not sure this type of questions are welcome on the site. In case tell me.

Let's define the $p$ mean as

$$M_p(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sqrt[p] { \frac 1n \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^p}$$

for $x_1, \dots, x_n > 0$.

Your goal is to prove that 
$$\dots \le M_{-2} \le M_{-1} = \mathcal{H} \le M_0 = \mathcal{G} \le M_1 = \mathcal{A} \le M_2 = \mathcal{Q} \le M_3 \dots$$

($M_0$ should be interpreted as the geometric mean, that is $M_0 = \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^n x_i}$. The notation is justified if we consider $p \to 0$ )

Ideally I would like to have as many proof as possible of the above, the more elegant the better. Extra points for not using any "nuclear bomb" in proving the result!

P.S. In case it is not clear, $\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{G}, \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{Q}$ 
are respectively the harmonic, geometric, arithmetic and quadratic means.

Comment: How are you defining $M_0$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 you are right! I edited :)

Comment: Are the $x_i$'s positive? Also, have you read this Wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I am not sure it needs to be so. I can see some troubles arising with the geometric mean though, so if you want to assume that, it is fine! :)

Comment: @Ant: consider $\{1/2,1/2,-1\}$. The arithmetic mean is $0$ but the harmonic mean is $1$.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you very much. I added the required hypothesis! :)

Comment: [Link to the AM-GM proof list](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $p\le q$, $p\ne0$, and $q\gt0$, $x^{q/p}$ is convex on $x\gt0$. Therefore, [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) says that
$$
\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^p\right)^{1/p}\le\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^q\right)^{1/q}\tag{1}
$$
For $p\le q$ and $q\lt0$, $(1)$ follows by applying $(1)$ to $1/x_k$ with $-q\le-p$ and $-q\gt0$, which would yield the reverse inequality, but then taking the reciprocal of both sides reverses the inequality a second time.

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{p\to0}\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^p\right)^{1/p}
&=\lim_{p\to0}\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^ne^{p\log(x_k)}\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\lim_{p\to0}\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left[1+p\log(x_k)+O(p^2)\right]\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\lim_{p\to0}\left(1+O(p^2)+\frac pn\sum_{k=1}^n\log(x_k)\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\lim_{p\to0}e^{\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(x_k)+O(p)}\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^{1/n}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks! I wait before I accept it in case someone comes up with something different, even though as others have said the proof using convexity is basically the only one

Answer (score 2):

The magic word is convexity, and there is really not much more to it.