# Proof of Geometric mean $\le$ Arithmetic mean

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is a problem from Spivak's Calculus.

If $a_1, \dots, a_n \ge 0$, then the "arithmetic mean"

$$ A_n= \frac{a_1+\cdots +a_n}{n}$$

and "geometric mean"

$$ G_n= \sqrt[n]{a_1 \dots a_n}$$

satisfy $G_n \le A_n$.

Suppose that $a_1 \lt A_n$. Then some $a_i \gt A_n$; for convenience, say $a_2 \gt A_n$. Let $\bar a_1=A_n$ and let $\bar a_2=a_1+a_2- \bar a_1$. Show that $\bar a_1 \bar a_2 \ge a_1a_2$.(This part is easily done). Why does repeating this process enough times eventually prove that $G_n \le A_n$? (This is another place where it is a good exercise to provide a formal proof by induction, as well as an informal reason.) When does equality hold in the formula $G_n \le A_n$?

I don't see how I can generalize this process to achieve the result. I would appreciate any hint, suggestions, or solutions.

Comment: You can get equality if all $a_i$ have the same value.

Comment: Yes but how do I prove the inequality using this?

Comment: See the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) on this topic.

Comment: also, [Proof about Am-Gm generalized] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863720/proof-about-am-gm-inequality-generalized)

Comment: Just count how many of them are already equal to the arithmetic mean. At each step it increases by 1.

Comment: For a big list, see [Proofs of AM-GM inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807)