# Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means

Tags: inequality

Prove that if $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are positive numbers, then $$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+...\frac{1}{x_n}}\leq \sqrt[n]{x_1\cdot x_2\cdot ... \cdot x_n}\leq\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$$

Comment: The right side is the AM/GM inequality. The left hand side, if you invert it, is the AM/GM inequality for $y_i=1/x_i$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality proofs of AM/GM.

Comment: see here the proof by Cauchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the lemma:
If $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$  are real positive numbers such thet $a_1.a_2. \cdots . a_n=1$, then
$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n \geq n$$
occur the equality if, only if, $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=1$. (You can proof this lemma by induction over $n$).

Now, lets proof the main result:
If $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are positive real numbers, then 
$$\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}\leq \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}$$

Indeed, if $g=\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$, follows that
$$g^n=a_1a_2\cdots a_n \Rightarrow g.g.\cdots.g=a_1a_2\cdots a_n \Rightarrow \frac{a_1}{g}.\frac{a_2}{g}.\cdots.\frac{a_n}{g}=1$$
By lemma above, follows that
$$\frac{a_1}{g}+\frac{a_2}{g}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{g} \geq n \Rightarrow $$
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n} \geq g \Rightarrow$$
$$\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}\leq \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}$$
the equaly occur if, only if
$$\frac{a_1}{g}=\frac{a_2}{g}=\cdots=\frac{a_n}{g}=1 \Leftrightarrow a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=g$$
i.e, the equality occur if, only if, every $a_i's$ are equals.

For proof that

$$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}} \leq \sqrt[n]{x_1.\cdots. x_n}$$

we can use the inequality between the meas arthimetic and geometric with the numbers $\frac{1}{x_1},\cdots,\frac{1}{x_n}$. Indeed,

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{x_1}.\cdots.\frac{1}{x_n}}\leq \frac{\frac{1}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}}{n}$$

therefore,

$$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}} \leq \sqrt[n]{x_1.\cdots. x_n}$$