# How to show AM-GM inequality using rearrangement inequality?

Tags: inequality, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

Wikipedia article on [Rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) (link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rearrangement_inequality&oldid=595994201)) says (without giving any citation for this claim):

> Many famous inequalities can be proved by the rearrangement inequality, such as the arithmetic mean – geometric mean inequality, the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, and Chebyshev's sum inequality.

How can the inequality of arithmetic and geometric mean be shown using rearrangement inequality?

(I had a look at this post: [Proofs of AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality). I did not see there a proof relying on rearrangement inequality - I hope I did not overlook it.)

Comment: Here's a relevant [link](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1642h1004526).

Comment: Also here: http://www.emis.de/journals/BMMSS/pdf/v21n2/v21n2p8.pdf.

Comment: @lulu . In your link, in the section Theorems Derived From Re-Arrangement, there is a typo in the def'n of $a_j$. The denominator should be $c^j$, not $c^i$. Otherwise it's very clear.

Comment: @user254665  You are right about the typo...and in the next line they use $a_i$ instead of $a_j$ which is, at least, less than ideal notation ($a_j$ having been newly defined and $i$ having been established as the dummy indexing variable).  But I do think the argument is clear.

Comment: Right . Since $c^i$ didn't make sense, I quickly read thru it to see if $c^j$ would make the argument valid, which it does, and I missed the  2nd typo. There are many many ways to prove the AGM inequality but I haven't seen this one before.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the proof of AM-GM based on rearrangement inequality following the hints given in Steele J.M. The Cauchy-Schwarz master class (MAA CUP 2004), Exercise 5.7, [page 84](https://books.google.com/books?id=7GDyRMrlgDsC&pg=PA84). (And the same proof can be certainly found in many other places.)

We first show that:

> For any $c_1,\dots,c_n>0$ we have
>   $$n\le \frac{c_1}{c_n}+\frac{c_2}{c_1}+\frac{c_3}{c_2}+\dots+\frac{c_n}{c_{n-1}}. \tag{1}$$

Indeed, if the permutation which reorders these $n$ numbers in the increasing order is $\sigma \colon \{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ then we have
\begin{gather*}
c_{\sigma(1)} \le c_{\sigma(2)} \le \dots \le c_{\sigma(n-1)} \le c_{\sigma(n)}\\
\frac1{c_{\sigma(n)}} \le \frac1{c_{\sigma(n-1)}} \le \dots \le \frac1{c_{\sigma(2)}} \le \frac1{c_{\sigma(1)}} 
\end{gather*}
and the rearrangement inequality gives us
$$c_1\cdot \frac1{c_n} + c_2\cdot\frac1{c_1} + \dots + c_n \frac1{c_{n-1}} \ge c_{\sigma(1)}\cdot\frac1{c_{\sigma(1)}}+c_{\sigma(2)}\cdot\frac1{c_{\sigma(2)}}+\dots+c_{\sigma(n)}\cdot\frac1{c_{\sigma(n)}}=n.$$

---

Simply by using $(1)$ for $c_n=x_1, c_2=x_1x_2, c_3=x_1x_2x_3, \dots, c_n=x_1x_2\cdots x_n$ we get:

> For any $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n>0$ we have 
>   $$n\le \frac{x_1}{x_1x_2\dots x_n}+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_n. \tag{2}$$

---

Making one more substitution, namely replacing $x_i$ by $ax_i$, we get that

> For any $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n>0$ and $a>0$ we have
>   $$n\le \frac{ax_1}{a^nx_1x_2\dots x_n}+ax_2+ax_3+\dots+ax_n. \tag{3}$$

---

Now if we choose $a$ in $(3)$ in such way that $a^nx_1x_2\dots x_n=1$, i.e., $a=\dfrac1{\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\dots x_n}}$, then the above equality becomes

\begin{align*}
n &\le a(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)\\
\frac1a &\le \frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}n\\
\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\dots x_n} &\le \frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}n
\end{align*}
So we get that AM-GM is true for any positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: Really nice proof! +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it might be useful to make also a CW post collecting some references where the proofs of AM-GM based on rearrangement inequality can be found. (Feel free to add more.)

**Online:**

- [Rearrangement Inequality](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1642h1004526) - A Problem Solver's Paradise at AoPS ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507032204/https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1642h1004526))
- [Rearrangement Inequality](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=598&lmm=0) at IMOMath - [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020200613/http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=598&lmm=0); [new website](https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=inequalitiesRearrangementChebyshev) - [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20220813055000/https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=inequalitiesRearrangementChebyshev). (Only the proof for $n=4$ is given here. But it seems that the generalization to arbitrary $n$ would be straightforward - although perhaps not that easy to write down formally. Which might be the reason for choosing a specific case, in order to illustrate the method more clearly.)
- Yue Kwok Choy: [Rearrangement Inequality](http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Rearrangement%20Inequality.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506134416/http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Rearrangement%20Inequality.pdf))

**Books:**

- R. B. Manfrino et al. *Inequalities: A Mathematical Olympiad Approach*, [Exercise 1.70](https://books.google.com/books?id=ebnEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA19).  The book also contains [solution for this exercise](https://books.google.com/books?id=ebnEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA125).
- Steele J.M. *The Cauchy-Schwarz master class* (MAA CUP 2004), Exercise 5.7, [page 84](https://books.google.com/books?id=7GDyRMrlgDsC&pg=PA84)

**Searches:**

In general, it is not easy to search for formulas, inequalities, proofs (or anything involving variables and mathematical expressions). But in this case both inequalities have names, so there are some reasonable choices:

- ["rearrangement inequality" arithmetic geometric mean](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rearrangement+inequality%22+arithmetic+geometric+mean)
- ["rearrangement inequality" "AM GM"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rearrangement+inequality%22+%22AM+GM%22)