# Extreme values(maximum,minimum is special cases), multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

We know that $ x,y,z >0$ and $x+y+z=1$

(i)For which $x,y,z$ will be $xyz$ maximum?

(ii)For which $x,y,z$ will be $x^2+y^2+z^2$ minimum?

I still have no idea, how to start the solution of these problems, can I maybe use somehow the Lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: For $(i)$ use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: You could use Lagrange multipliers. Alternatively, you could uses standard inequalities like AM/GM or Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for (i) use that $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$$
for (ii) use that $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\le \sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}}$$

Comment: Could you maybe help me how to use it exactly in this case?

Comment: pluggiing $$x+y+z=1$$ in the inequalities

Comment: So the maximum will be at $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$?

Answer (score 2):

For $(i)$ use  [Proofs of AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality)

For $(ii)$

$$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x+y+z)^2=(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\ge0$$

Comment: Can you give me just a hint, how can I use it exactly for $(ii)$?

Comment: @Herrpeter, So we have $$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\ge(x+y+z)^2=1^2$$

Comment: So I get that $x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz=1$?

Comment: @Herrpeter, So we get $$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge\dfrac13$$