# Maximize $\frac{a^2b}{(1+a+ab)^3}$ subject to $a,b\ge1$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Maximize $\frac{a^2b}{(1+a+ab)^3}$ subject to $a,b\ge1$

I came up with it while solving this problem: [Extreme values(maximum,minimum is special cases), multivariable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280847/extreme-valuesmaximum-minimum-is-special-cases-multivariable-calculus)

Note: The two problems are basically equivalent, but I wonder if one derives it back through the same path or maybe solves it in an easier way.

Comment: Do you know of the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Show that $$\frac{a^2b}{(1+a+ab)^3}\le \frac{1}{27}$$ for $$a,b\geq 1$$

Comment: Yes, by AM-GM: $(1+a+ab)^3\ge (3\sqrt[3]{1\cdot a\cdot ab})^3$

Comment: why the $-1$? I don't know, what is wrong?