# Is a visual proof to show below inequality?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, real-numbers, alternative-proof

Suppose $x_1x_2x_3=y^3$ and $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R},x_1\neq x_2\neq x_3,\text{All of them are positive numbers}$
we need to show $$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)(1+x_3)\geq (1+y)^3$$ This inequality can proved by algebraic work ,but I am looking for a visual (or something like this) proof. 
   I am thankful in advance for any idea .

Comment: A question (not much effect on the main problem): If $x_1\neq x_2\neq x_3$, then when does the equality holds in the inequality?

Comment: There might be an inequality of this kind; but additional assumptions are needed. When $x_1=1$, $x_2=-2$, $x_3=-4$, $y=2$ then $x_1x_2x_3=y^3$, but your inequality is violated.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding both sides we get: $1+ x_1 + x_2+ x_1x_2 + x_3 + x_2x_3+x_1x_3+x_1x_2x_3>1+ 3y+3y^2+y^3$. Use AM-GM inequality next: $x_1+x_2+x_3 > 3y, x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1 > 3y^2$, and add these up. Thus its proven.Note that this is still "algebraic" but it gets readers start. And in fact, the interpretation is just interpret geometrically the AM-GM inequality for $3$ positive numbers. Hope it helps. One of these popular topics could be found in Roger Nelsen's book on "Proofs Without Words" of the MAA back in the $90$'s.

Comment: FWIW the $n=2$ case of AM-GM has several simple "visual" proofs e.g. [\[1\]](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT725/AMGM/AMGM.1.html), [\[2\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/830897), [\[3\]](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/school-of-mathematics/studying-here/undergraduate-study/before-you-get-here/proofs/amgm).