# Prove $x+y+z\geq3$ given $xyz=1$ and $0<x,y,z\in\mathbb{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, field-theory, symmetric-polynomials

Prove $x+y+z\geq3$ given $xyz=1$ and $0<x,y,z\in\mathbb{F}$. 
Secondly, show that $x+y+z=3\iff x=y=z=1$.

($\mathbb{F}$ is the ordered field)

I've tried applying the following lemma with no success yet:

> If $0<a<1$ and $1<b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{F}$ then $1+ab<a+b$

Comment: Do you know AM-GM? :)

Comment: is there a reason why you specifically want to use the lemma? theres only a handful of ways in which $xyz=1$ even with the inclusion of complex numbers.

Comment: What is $\Bbb F$?

Comment: @Vaas thought it could help as it was previously proven (one problem earlier)

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality/1665056#1665056) proves the more general result, your question is the case $n=3.$

Comment: @Arthur I think it's an ordered field.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes, thanks for clarifying

Comment: I have no idea about field. Can I do the problem using Calculus?(Multiplier). It is easier.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan yes!

Comment: Should I write the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D=(x+y+z)^3-27xyz$ and $S=x+y+z$. Then
$$
2D=(S+6z)(x-y)^2+(S+6x)(y-z)^2+(S+6y)(z-x)^2\geq 0
$$
and so $(x+y+z)^3\geq 27xyz=27$ and therefore $x + y + z\geq 3$. We have $x + y +z=3$ iff $D=0$ iff $x=y=z$.

Comment: I found this proof, but you beat me. +1.

Comment: You may need to show $a^3\ge b^3\implies a\ge b$ using ordered field axioms for completeness but that isn’t hard. +1

Comment: Why is this mandatory? $$ 2D=\sum_{\text{cyc}}(x+y+7z)(x-y)^2\geq 0 $$

Comment: @SlavikEgorov The equality holds by direct verification and the inequality because $x,y,z>0$.

Comment: Could you explain that cyc saying under the sigma and what did you apply to get that expression?

Comment: @SlavikEgorov I have rewritten the result without the cyclical summation notation. To verify the identity, just expand both sides.

Comment: Also, how do you prove $ x+y+z =3\iff x=y=z=1 $ ?

Comment: @SlavikEgorov In $$2D=(S+6z)(x-y)^2+(S+6x)(y-z)^2+(S+6y)(z-x)^2,$$ $x=y=z$ is the only way to make the RHS $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$, $g(x,y,z)=xyz$

Solve the equations $\bigtriangledown f=\lambda \bigtriangledown g \tag {1}$

$g(x,y,z)=1 \tag{2}$

$x, y, z \ge 0$

$\implies$ $1=\lambda yz\tag{*}$
$1=\lambda xz\tag{**}$
$1=\lambda xy\tag{***}$
$g(x,y,z)=1 \tag{****}$
$\implies$ $x=y=z=\lambda$

Appliying in (2) we get the desired result.