# How to prove inequality using investigation of extremum?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i  \geq \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} $$
I need to prove this inequality for positive numbers $x_1$,...,$x_n$ using investigation of extremum, but I even don`t know from what to start, pls help.

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\geq \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Comment: Yes,you are right,sorry

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality

Comment: This is the classical AM/GM inequality.

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, thank you!