# A little confusion about AM-GM proof

Tags: inequality, induction, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

In Cauchy's forward-backward induction proof, why can we substitute $x_k=\frac{x_1+x_2+ ... +x_{k-1}}{k-1}$  without losing generality?

Comment: Can you give reference to what proof you are referring exactly?

Comment: Sure, the first proof mentioned in [link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/), or this one: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658371/626138)

Answer (score 0):

We can not substitute it of course in the general case, but if we'll prove that for $P(k): \frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_k}{k}\geq\sqrt[k]{x_1x_2...x_k}$ and fo $x_i>0$ the following statements are true:
$$P(2)$$
$$P(k)\Rightarrow P(2k)$$ and
$$P(k)\Rightarrow P(k-1)$$ then it's obvious that we'll prove AM-GM.

For the proof of the last statement we can assume $x_k=\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_{k-1}}{k-1}$ because we assumed that $P(k)$ is true for all positive $k$ numbers $x_i$ and from here

it's true for $k$ positive numbers $x_1$,...,$x_{k-1}$,$\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_{k-1}}{k-1}$, which gives that $P(k-1)$ is true.

Comment: This way aren't we proving $P(k)\Rightarrow P(k-1)$ for some particular sequence of $k$ positive numbers rather than all sequence of $k$ positive numbers?

Comment: $P(k)\rightarrow P(k-1)$ it's: with assuming that AM-GM is true for all positives $x_1$, $x_2$,...,$x_k$ we need to prove that AM-GM is true for all positives $x_1$,..., $x_{k-1}.$ The proof of this statement you saw already.