# Question about the last step of this AM-GM inequality proof

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

Proof of the AM-GM inequality I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/692444/678074)

> As $(\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_2})^2 \geq 0$ we have $$\sqrt{x_1 \cdot x_2}
>  \leq \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}.$$ Applying this inequality twice, we get
> $$(x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4)^{\frac{1}{4}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x_1 x_2}+\sqrt{x_3
>  x_4}}{2} \leq \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}{4}.$$ By induction, it is not
> difficult to see that $$(x_1 \cdots x_{2^k})^{\frac{1}{2^k}} \leq
>  \frac{x_1+\ldots+x_{2^k}}{2^k} \tag{1}$$ for all $k \geq 1$.
>
> It remains to fill the gaps between the powers of two. So let
> $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be arbitrary  positive numbers and choose $k$ such
> that $n\leq 2^k$. We set
>
> $$\alpha_i := \begin{cases} x_i & i \leq n \\ A & n< i \leq 2^k
>  \end{cases}$$
>
> where $A:= \frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n}$. Applying $(1)$ to the
> $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{2^k})$ yields
>
> $$\bigg( x_1 \ldots x_n A^{2^k-n} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2^k}} \leq
>  \frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n+(2^k-n) A}{2^k} = A.$$
>
> Hence,
>
> $$(x_1 \ldots x_n)^{1/n} \leq A = \frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n}.$$

I understand everything except the very last step:

> Hence,
>
> $$(x_1 \ldots x_n)^{1/n} \leq A = \frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n}.$$

How did he reach the conclusion? The only thing he proved is that

$$\bigg( x_1 \ldots x_n A^{2^k-n} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2^k}} \leq A$$

But I don't see how this allows him to reach the final conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left(x_1 \cdots x_n A^{2^k - n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^k}} \leq A &\Rightarrow x_1 \cdots x_n A^{2^k - n} \leq A^{2^k} \\
&\Rightarrow x_1 \cdots x_n \leq A^n \\
&\Rightarrow (x_1 \cdots x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq A
\end{align*}