# Different Versions of Jensen's Inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, jensen-inequality

According to wikipedia:

> Jensen's inequality is
>
> ${\displaystyle f(tx_{1}+(1-t)x_{2})\leq tf(x_{1})+(1-t)f(x_{2}).}$

With this, I can easily prove Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, in other words to prove that:

${\frac  {x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots +x_{n}}{n}}\geq {\sqrt[ {n}]{x_{1}\cdot x_{2}\cdots x_{n}}}\,,$

My problem is that my teacher didn't define Jensen's inequality in the same way above but rather:

> Let $X$ be a **discrete** random variable with finite expected value
> and let $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. then:
> $h(E[X])\leq E[h(X)]$

How can I reach (prove) the first version using my professor's version of the inequality, so I can prove the Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means?

Comment: Take $X$ with distribution concentrated on the set $\{x_1, x_2\}$ with masses $t$ and $1-t.$

Comment: Proving that the definition of convexity implies the expectation variety is not entirely straightforward.

Comment: @copper.hat I suspect the reciprocal of what OP is asking, i.e. what you are comenting, is not true for general discrete variables but rather _finite discrete._

Comment: @WilliamM. I suspect you are correct, but I wanted the OP to realise that, while equivalent, it is not immediate (unless you are familiar with some facts about convex functions).

Answer (score 1):

The way your prof stated Jensen's inequality is more general. The inequality
$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2),\quad t\in[0,1]\quad [1]$$
is a special case of

$$f(E[X])\leq E[f(X)]\quad \text{Jensen's inequality}$$

for $f$ convex, where the random variable $X$ has two-point support $\{x_1,x_2\}$ with respective probability masses $t,1-t.$  However, it is important to note that $[1]$ is actually the *definition* of $f$ being a convex function, so one doesn't require Jensen's inequality to justify it.

Comment: Also fyi the RV doesn't need to be discrete in Jensen's inequality

Comment: Do you have a proof using my professor's version? If [1] is the definition of  being a convex function, then why wikipedia call it Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @David Pls see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Comment: And as I explained, it is also an immediate corollary of Jensen's inequality (but unnecessary)

Comment: @David I did answer your question...

Comment: Thanks, so given my professors verions (which is well common) how to prove Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means? I didn't find anything online.

Comment: I thought you said from here, you are able to prove the AM-GM inequality? What was your confusion in that proof exactly?

Comment: I want to use my professors versions not [1]

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_using_Jensen's_inequality

Comment: You have to use [1] extended to $n$ points instead of just 2 points though

Comment: Thanks again, can you verify if this answer is correct? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1665241/1014640 it didn't use [1]