# Prove the general arithmetic-geometric mean inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove that the general arithmetic-geometric mean inequality
\begin{equation*}
(a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n})^\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n}}{n}
\end{equation*}
holds for all $a_{i}$ positive real numbers.

I keep getting stuck half way. This is review material for me (which I feel like I should be getting easily, but that's not the case unfortunately).

Comment: Try using the concavity of the logarithm. Other proofs can be found here : [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: Why is this tagged ([tag:calculus])? Do you want some solution using calculus in some way?

Comment: I guess I should add "analysis" tag.. its a reviwe for my analysis course. and the prof said we should know these things, but i can't seem to get it.

Comment: Have you looked at the proofs given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality)? Have you looked at [other questions about this inequality](http://www.google.com/search?q=AM+GM+inequality+site:math.stackexchange.com)? For example questions linked in [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407277/a-question-on-mean-value-inequality).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you!

Comment: I refer to my answer to

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552780/is-tran-geq-nn-deta-for-a-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-a-in-m/1095152#1095152

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has the solution to this problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_induction_using_basic_calculus

If you would like to attempt it again before looking at the solution, here is a hint:

Attempt a proof by induction (as usual, consisting of the base case, hypothesis, induction step and then a conclusion). The base case is $n=1$. For the hypothesis, choose some non-negative real number $n$. For the induction step, rearrange the inequality and write
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a_1+...+a_n+a_{n-1}}{n+1}-(a_1...a_na_{n-1})^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\geq 0.
\end{equation*}
If you consider the quantity on the left as a function $f$, then the problem reduces to analysing the critical points of $f$ using tools from calculus. Is this okay? You said you got stuck half-way so I am happy to go through anything in more detail if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach which may or may not work:

Partial differential of the left hand side wrt $a_k$:

$$\frac{(a_k)^{-(n-1)/n}}{n} \prod_{i \neq k}(a_i)^{1/n}$$

and the right hand side:

$\frac{1}{n}$, now one could try to show this is bigger than the other.